# How to configure DataSourceRealm with bcrypt

Tags: mysql, tomcat, bcrypt, tomcat9

I am looking for some tips how I can configure a DataSourceRealm with an MySQL database including bcrypt-hashed passwords. Unfortunately, I am already struggling with getting the DataSource running - even with clear text passwords.

I have edited the conf/context.xml and added the DataSource as follows:

```
<Context>
[...]
<Resource name="jdbc/MYRESOURCE" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
username="USER" password="PASSWORD" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://my.database.com:3306/DATABASE?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;autoReconnect=true" />
</Context>
```

The server.xml contains the Realm as follows:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
dataSourceName="jdbc/MYRESOURCE"
userTable="myuser" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"
userRoleTable="myuser_roles" roleNameCol="role"/>
```

When I start the Tomcat, it says that my context "jdbc/MYRESOURCE" is not found.

I also tried to add another  to the conf/context.xml which results in the Tomcat is not starting at all. Also same, if I add the  into the  of the conf/server.xml

What is wrong here? Can somebody help?

Comment: Try putting the resource in the [`<GlobalNamingResources>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/globalresources.html) block of your `server.xml`.

Comment: Hi Piotr, Thanks! That is working now for clear text passwords. How can I add the bcrypt-hash now? Is it supported by the CredentialHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a custom integration on GitHub, which supports bcrypt passwords.

I just put the JAR into the 'lib' directory and switched the standard "MessageDigestCredentialHandler" to the new "BCryptoCredentialHandler" as described on GitHub.

https://github.com/andreacomo/tomcat-bcrypt/

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the plaintext part, you declare your JDBC `<Resource>` at a webapp context, so:

- either declare the `<Realm>` in the same context with a `localDataSource="true"`,
- or declare the JDBC `Resource` globally inside [`<GlobalNamingResources>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/globalresources.html).

Concerning [**bcrypt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt): none of the two credential handlers in Tomcat (`MessageDigestCredentialHandler` and `SecretKeyCredentialHandler`) supports either the format used by bcrypt or the password hashing. If you want reuse hashed passwords from another source, it won't be possible without writing your own `CredentialHandler`.

The only storage formats supported are:

> - `plainText` - the plain text credentials if no algorithm is specified
> - `encodedCredential` - a hex encoded digest of the password digested using the configured digest
> - `{MD5}encodedCredential` - a Base64 encoded MD5 digest of the password
> - `{SHA}encodedCredential` - a Base64 encoded SHA1 digest of the password
> - `{SSHA}encodedCredential` - 20 character salt followed by the salted SHA1 digest Base64 encoded
> - `salt$iterationCount$encodedCredential` - a hex encoded salt, iteration code and a hex encoded credential, each separated by $

(source [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/credentialhandler.html))

However the supported hashing functions are similar to bcrypt, so you can use, e.g.:

```xml
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
       dataSourceName="jdbc/MYRESOURCE"
       userTable="myuser"
       userNameCol="username"
       userCredCol="password"
       userRoleTable="myuser_roles"
       roleNameCol="role">
    <CredentialHandler class="org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler" />
</Realm>
```

and have a format as secure as bcrypt.

You can hash your passwords using:

```sh
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/digest.sh -h org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler <your_password>
```

from the command line, where `$CATALINA_HOME` is Tomcat's directory.

Comment: Hi Piotr, unfortunately, this will not work for me, because I have a database with bcrypt passwords already. Nevertheless, I found an integration on GitHub, which works.

Comment: @Peter_O: you mean [Andrea's BCryptoCredentialHandler](https://github.com/andreacomo/tomcat-bcrypt)?

Comment: Yes, I mean this one. I posted an separate answer to push it, so other people do not need to search in the comment section.